# Anonymous File Upload

Tags: networking, debian, vpn

What would be the best way to store files on internet without having any user acc or transparency of who will download it?

is TOR a good way to achieve this? I got a raspberry as source to send data to a client which has to be completely anonymous!

------ Edit ------

I got a rpi as a passive network monitor (bridge mode) on a target network (my own testing lab/network). now i want to send the pcap dumps to a destination where i can analyse them.

The main topic is to reduce the amount of data which is leading to the file destination and to the client which is analyzing the files.

What would be the best way to copy the pcap files from the rpi to the client without uncloaking the client?

Comment: TOR is slow and highly monitored by NSA, eeee, because they created it. But thats another story. To send files anonymously you need a client that create a Point2Point SSH 2048 Tunnel. That will stop tracking but you will still know who sent the file, if you log it. If you don't log anything then nobody will know. You can also use BitTorrent Synch?

Comment: what this has to do with raspberry, besides having it somewhere in the house?

Comment: we need more information to help you. Try an detail a how and why a user(not the Pi) and what the Pi is expected to do.

Comment: is there a performance gap while encrypt data with SSH 2048 on a rpi?

Answer (score 1):

Steganography, a video of a cat, and youtube.

Or alternatively, an F2F network.

You don't make it clear whether you need to keep secret: (a) the content being transferred, (b) the sender, or (c) the recipient or recipients.  It may not be easy to keep all 3 completely 100% guaranteed secret.

When you mention tor, you probably mean [Tor's hidden services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29#Hidden_services).

Comment: It is basically the recipient(s)

Answer (score -1):

You might want to have a look at [Freenet](https://freenetproject.org/)

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.